# How do you keep the Mac from accessing the dvd drive on resuming from sleep?

Tags: mac, sleep

Whenever I resume my mac from sleep (after it has been sleeping for a while), it seeks the dvd drive which can be a little noisy, especially in a meeting.  Is there a way to keep it from doing this?

Comment: ahh, is *that* what that noise is? I thought it was a bit loud to be the harddrive!

Comment: My MacBook Pro no longer does this since upgrading to Lion.

Comment: My MacBook Pro (early 2008) still does even after upgrading to Lion.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9752168&tstart=0) on Apple's support forum, setting the region of your drive may help. You can do this by putting in a DVD from your region.

Comment: I have played DVDs in my mac so I believe I have set the region of my drive (vaguely remember doing this).  It still does the auto check on wakeup.  This is the same result as this comment from the link:

"I've just set the region code
however, it did not stop the dvd auto check on wakeup"